# Table cells flushed white

Tags: php, mysql

Upon running the below SQL statement (which works perfectly) I've found that all tables in my database are flushed white.

Any idea as to why this happening?

```
        // check database for necessary updates

$update = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rent WHERE colour='3C0'");

while($row_update = mysql_fetch_array( $update )) {

$datetime_lower   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $min);
$datetime_upper   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $max);
$datetime_compare = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', $row_update['pDate']);

if ($datetime_lower < $datetime_compare && $datetime_upper > $datetime_compare) {

    // date is between do nothing

        mysql_close($update);

    } else {

    // date is not between so update

    echo "date is not between";

    $update_result = mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET colour='F0F0F0' WHERE substr(pDate, 0, 10) NOT BETWEEN $min AND $max && colour='3C0'");

    mysql_close($update_result);
}
}
```

I've included a few pictures.

This is how it is meant to look like (above code omitted):

http://i51.tinypic.com/143gpef.jpg

This is how it currently looks like (above code present):

http://i54.tinypic.com/2lwm4xg.jpg

Comment: by any chance are you outputting HTML for that table using "colour"? if so, HTML/CSS use the US spelling of "color" thus any attempt to change it would not work and the default "white" would be applied.

Comment: @scunliffe +1 for the CSS hint; another virtual +1 for the spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop appears to go through all the results from your table. It appears that on each iteration of the loop, you check the date first in PHP, then you check the date again in your update query, and update all matching rows to F0F0F0.

I don't know why your code is changing the colour to white instead of #F0F0F0, since there is no white or fff in your code, so all I can do is suggest something to make your code more efficient.

Instead of updating all rows on each iteration of the while loop, if you have an `id` column (Primary Key with Auto-increment) in your `rent` table, you can use this value in your while loop instead of having to test the date a second time.

```
$update = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rent WHERE colour='3C0'");
while($row_update = mysql_fetch_array( $update )) {
    $datetime_lower   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $min);
    $datetime_upper   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $max);
    $datetime_compare = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g:i a', $row_update['pDate']);
    if ($datetime_lower < $datetime_compare && $datetime_upper > $datetime_compare) {
        // date is between do nothing
        mysql_close($update);
    } else {
        // date is not between so update
        echo "date is not between";
        $update_result = mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET colour='F0F0F0' WHERE id=" . $row_update['id'] . " && colour='3C0'");
        mysql_close($update_result);
    }
}
```